# JVM Behavioral Options

Tags: java, jvm

1. Has anyone used the following JVM behavioral Options ?

   - -XX:+FailOverToOldVerifier: Fail over to old verifier when the new type checker fails.
   - -XX:-RelaxAccessControlCheck: Relax the access control checks in the verifier
   - -XX:-UseSpinning:  Enable naive spinning on Java monitor before entering operating system thread synchronizaton code.
   - -XX:PreBlockSpin:  Spin count variable for use with -XX:+UseSpinning. Controls the maximum spin iterations allowed before entering operating system thread synchronization code.
   - -XX:+UseSplitVerifier: Use the new type checker with StackMapTable attributes.
2. Can you share any additional details on these options and the scenarios in which any of these options were used ?
3. Any benefits anticipated or observed in using these VM options ?

Reference: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used

```
-XX:+UseSplitVerifier
```

For use with JVM agents that do bytecode instrumentation BUT don't take into account the StackMapTable. (which is the case for all bytecode instrumentation agents coded for JVMs pre 1.7)

More info (and a bit of rant too) [here](http://chrononsystems.com/blog/java-7-design-flaw-leads-to-huge-backward-step-for-the-jvm)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some old Java 5 programs use UseSpinning. Java 7u40 and above report it has been removed. I only notices it was used because of the warning java spits out.
I see PreBlockSpin needs to be enabled only with UseSpinning.